# Why can't I set auto increment to a field that is used as a foreign key in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want both id's to auto increment:
[image: tables]

I get this error when synchronizing the model:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 3780: Referencing column 'taskList_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'fk_task_taskList' are incompatible.
SQL Code:
        ALTER TABLE `easyManage`.`task` 
        ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_task_taskList`
          FOREIGN KEY (`taskList_id`)
          REFERENCES `easyManage`.`taskList` (`id`)
          ON DELETE CASCADE
          ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Comment: Seems that `id` and `taskList_id` have different data types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tasklist_id in table task is varchar(55). It has to be int to hold id from table tasklist

Answer (score 0):

Your `task.tasklist_id` is VARCHAR(55).

And your `tasklist.id` is an INT.

They should be of the same data type.

And - if you say: "I want both id's to auto increment" - I take it you mean `task.id` and `tasklist.id` - and not `task.tasklist_id` - and then everything should work just fine.